# json.loads -> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'

Tags: python, json, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I am using the Python (version: 3.4.4) Pyramid framework to receive a json request and convert the received json to a python object using json.loads. When using TestApp to unit test the app like listed below, it all works fine, however, when using through Apache mod_wsgi I do receive the following error in json.loads(...)

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'

Any idea why?

The view code:

```
@view_config(route_name='api.analysis', request_method='POST', renderer='json')
def fetch_my_info(request):
  data = json.loads(request.json_body, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
  ...
```

The test code:

```
  self.testApp = TestApp(app)
  response = self.testApp.post_json('/v1/info/analysis', params={"id", "123"})
  ...
```

Comment: I'm guessing Pyramid is already converting the json to a dict for you?

Comment: Sounds like it's already a dict

Comment: Why in the test with mod_wsgi and not in a unit test with TestApp?

Comment: Why do you expect two unrelated pieces of software to behave the same without reading the documentation first?

Comment: @thebjorn: Why do you assume I didn't read the documentation? I can't remember you asked me, or putting in the text above. I exactly did, and can't find an answer there. Could you please point me the link in the documentation explaining the difference? Thanks you very much.

Comment: You don't show where the variable `content` comes from in your code sample. Could you add the missing lines?

Comment: @AntoineLeclair: sorry about that, I corrected the mistake (content=request.json_body)

Comment: Why do I assume you haven't read the documentation? Perhaps because the answer is in the fourth bullet point in the documentation... You might want to consider reading the documentation of new frameworks instead of just searching it -- I'm confident it will help you out in the long run ;-)   ps: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/testapp.html#making-json-requests

Comment: @thebjorn: i know that documentation, and no it's not new like you assume, and not no contains the required info, but thanks for the link, very much appreciated. The problem seem to be in how pyramid decodes the pyramid json_body property in the request which is in de pyramid documentation, but not all scenarios seem to be documented well, that is: if you send a json object the json_body will be a python dict. if the submitted json however is a string, the json_body is a string...

Comment: What is a "json object"?  json data is always text (and almost always utf-8 encoded text).  What you're describing is automatic serialization of a python dict to json-data (text) on sending, and deserialization from json-data (text) to a python object (dict) on receiving. Substitute string for dict in the previous sentence for what happens "when json_body is a string".  From the docs: "[post_json] params are dumped to json and put in the body of the request" and "Request.json_body is a property that returns a JSON-decoded representation of the request body".

Answer (score 2):

`request.json_body` has already decoded the body into a python object for you. If you wish to decode it yourself then you should use the raw body via `loads(request.body.decode(request.charset), ...)`.

Comment: Encoding is the second argument to `json.loads(s, econding=None, ...)` but it defaults to `utf-8`. You only need to decode the string yourself it it's UCS-2 or similar:  "If `s` is a `str` instance and is encoded with an ASCII based encoding other than utf-8 (e.g. latin-1) then an appropriate `encoding` name must be specified. Encodings that are not ASCII based (such as UCS-2) are not allowed and should be decoded to `unicode` first."

Comment: That's fine but in this context it should actually be explicitly `request.charset` (which will default to utf-8 if the request does not specify further in the content type.. and conveniently application/json defaults to utf-8 so the defaults match) which I'll update my answer to reflect.